# How to import import blank XML tags into a Number column of a table using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have created a stored procedure which converts a XML file into a SQL Server data table. This works well when there are values in each tag for number formatted columns but does not work if the tag is empty. Is there a way to convert blank to null or a way to ignore blanks within the stored procedure? Here is a simplified version of the procedure.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SHPReportDataXML] 
    @XML XML
AS 
    INSERT dbo.SHPReportData ([Weight], [WeightUQ]) 
        SELECT
            [Weight] = SHPReportData.value('(RawDataItem/Weight)[1]', 'DECIMAL(10, 2)'),
            [WeightUQ] = SHPReportData.value('(RawDataItem/UQ)[1]', 'VARCHAR(2)')
        FROM
            @XML.nodes('RawData') c (SHPReportData);
```

Comment: You do not show enough... Please provide your tables DDL and a working and a non-working sample XML. This is best served as [mcve] for easy *copy-and-paste* reproduction of your issue. And please tag with your RDBMS (vendor and version).. I assume this is SQL-Server... Please try to think with the head of a stranger... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are receiving 0 or conversion errors for rows with this tag containing empty string.
You can shred XML to a varchar value and then do verification and type conversions in TSQL:

```
 SELECT
    [Weight] =
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(SHPReportData.value('(RawDataItem/Weight)[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)'),'') = '' THEN NULL
       ELSE CAST(SHPReportData.value('(RawDataItem/Weight)[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)') AS DECIMAL(10,2)) END,
     [WeightUQ] = SHPReportData.value('(RawDataItem/UQ)[1]', 'VARCHAR(2)')
  FROM
     @XML.nodes('RawData') c (SHPReportData);
```

Comment: Better than `CASE WHEN ISNULL()...` was a simple `NULLIF()`, which will return `NULL` as replacement for a given value. And even better was an XQuery `cast as xs:`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution works, but this can be done better:

--The XML carries one decimal value, one empty node and one node with a blank.
--Add the node with the non-castable value "hello" to test the methods with this too.

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'<a>123.456</a>
                   <a/>
                   <a>   </a>';

--add one more with a non-castable value
--                   <a>hello</a>';
```

--The "staging" approach: Read the string and proceed externally

```
SELECT a.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') worksInAnyCase
FROM @xml.nodes('/a') A(a)
```

--The type-safe approach will fail for non-decimals

```
SELECT a.value('text()[1]','decimal(6,3)') FailsForHello
FROM @xml.nodes('/a') A(a)
```

--XQuery's cast can help here

```
SELECT a.value('text()[1] cast as xs:decimal?','decimal(6,3)') WorksImplicitly
FROM @xml.nodes('/a') A(a)
```

--TRY_CAST helps too (needs v2012+)

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(a.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DECIMAL(6,3)) castedIfPossible
FROM @xml.nodes('/a') A(a)
```

--NULLIF might help too, but hello will pass by

```
SELECT NULLIF(a.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'') NullForBlanks
FROM @xml.nodes('/a') A(a)
```

--The accepted solution fails for hello too

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(a.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)'),'') = '' THEN NULL ELSE CAST(a.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)') AS decimal(6,3)) END FailsForHello
FROM @xml.nodes('/a') A(a)
```

My favourite was the XQuery cast...